# Does forcing file download with php headers affect my bandwidth?

Tags: php, javascript, header, bandwidth

I was looking for a front-end js solution to this problem/concept of forcing file downloads in the browser.  Basically, I want to make the browser download a file via some js event.  I know in HTML5 we have the download property but its only supported in Chrome and the end-user still has to actually click on the link and I can't trigger it.  But the lack of browser support is more problematic for my needs.

So, I thought that I would use PHP and "Content-Disposition: attachment" which is working great but now that it's server side code I wonder if it will affect my bandwidth.  The files downloaded are external and do not live on my servers.

Also, while "download.php?file=http://domain.com/image.jpg" downloads the file for me, I can't figure out how to initiate a download via an ajax request to "download.php?file=http://domain.com/image.jpg"

Any ideas?

Here is a part of the php code:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile("$filename");
```

Ok, well one way to initiate a download on the front-end is to apply a X-Frame-Options header to download.php and then open the image in an iframe, as in add this to download.php:

```
header('X-Frame-Options: DENY');
```

And then do this with JS/jquery:

```
$("body").append(<iframe src="download.php?file=http://domain.com/image.jpg"></iframe>);
```

But I am still using download.php and will get a bandwidth cost so it's not ideal.  Any other ideas?  I just want to display a bunch of images on the page and allow the user to click one button to download them all.  Images are not hosted by me and I don't want to take the bandwidth hit.

In terms of the download HTML5 attribute and not being able to trigger it, the jquery click or trigger click fails but this code did allow me to trigger the download programmatically:

```
var clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
clickEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
$("a")[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

But, this download attribute is only supported in Chrome, so I am getting closer but not there yet.  Anyone?

Comment: Can you show some code? And what exactly is your question - I don't really understand how Ajax comes into play here

Comment: Ajax cannot do file downloads - it's a background operation. You'd need to use `window.location = 'download.php.....'` to force a foreground operation.

Comment: my download php file works great, you go to it and it downloads a file specified in the query, when i go to download.php?file=http://domain.com/image.jpg - it downloads http://domain.com/image.jpg, but I am trying to download more than one file so I would like to make a call (ajax call) to download.php for each file.  I can make the ajax call return the image but not download it.

Comment: Why do you want to feed the browser multiple downloads of images?

Comment: Because I want the end user to be able to download a bunch of images by just clicking one button (without bandwidth costs to my server)

Comment: One thing that springs to mind is are you able to create a zip file of all these images, or even a zip file based on the selection made by your end user. It won't necessarily reduce bandwidth, but it might mean less hogging of bandwidth if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using PHP to fetch the remote file, and then the requesting web browser would be downloading from your PHP server. Yes, it is affecting bandwidth by having to copy the entire contents of the original source to your server, and sending that copied content to the browser.

Essentially, you have a basic proxy that may be abused by people sending requests for large files to exhaust your data transfer limit if you do not filter the link to the download request.

Also, I don't see why you would want to start a download from an AJAX request, even if it were possible. The file to download should not affect the page that is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that makes sense.  I posted my PHP code above, I was hoping that this was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If I go to a page and it starts an automatic download of a file, I click cancel and try and close my browser down. I suspect a lot of other people would be of the same opinion and hopefully manufacturers of browsers. I'd like it if I was prompted 'would you like to download this file'.

To answer your question if the files are being downloaded from Server B then it would be the bandwidth on Server B that would be affected.

Comment: This is my main question, the file is downloaded from Server B and it definitely has a bandwidth cost, but what about my server?  If it was all JS I would be sure that my server is not using bandwidth but since I have php code that gets the file, I wonder if it makes a difference.

Comment: At my current workplace we have our javascript files on a CDN. Someone visiting one of our webpages is served that page from our web server, but the link to the javascript points to the CDN server. Therefore the bandwidth to the web server isn't being affected. I've re-read your post and the comments other people have made and it seems to me that your code is pulling the files from server B to your server, then pushing those files out again. So, this will affect bandwidth on both servers.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you are right and that is why I am trying to figure out a complete front-end solution.  It is unfortunate that only Chrome supports the HTML5 download attribute which gets this done.